# Problema al generar cadena dentro de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: base-de-datos, stored-procedure, plsql

Este procedimiento me debería arrojar en una cadena los números del uno al 10. ¿Cómo podria arreglarlo?

```
  PROCEDURE CAP_PR_MOS_NUM(PI_Num   in integer,
                           Pv_Resp  out varchar2,
                           PV_ERROR out varchar2)IS
  --BLOQUE DE DECLARACIONES
  VAR1 INTEGER:=0;
  LN_SUM NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    --BLOQUE DE VALIDACIONES
    IF PI_Num IS NOT NULL OR PI_Num > 0 THEN
       WHILE (VAR1 <=10)LOOP
       VAR1:=VAR1|| TO_CHAR(LN_SUM) || ','; 
       Pv_Resp:=LN_SUM;
       VAR1:= VAR1+1;
    END LOOP;
    ELSE
     PV_ERROR:='NUMERO INVALIDO';
    END IF;  


  END CAP_PR_MOS_NUM;
```

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: `VAR1` es tipo entero y es supuestamente tu contador, y le estas asignando la cadena!

Answer (score 0):

Tus errores se concentran en:

```
VAR1 := VAR1|| TO_CHAR(LN_SUM) || ',';
```

Primero, la variable LN_SUM es inicializada con `0` y no modifica su valor a lo largo del *script*.

Por otro lado, la variable `VAR1` es de tipo `INTEGER` y tratas de asignarle el resultado de una concatenación de cadenas de texto.

Necesitas una variable de un tipo capaz de almacenar cadenas de texto, por ejemplo, `varchar2`, para ir *armando* el resultado, y luego concatenar la misma variable de control del `loop`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Resultado varchar2(50) := '';
Numero Integer := 1;

begin
  while (Numero <= 10) loop
    Resultado := Resultado || to_char(Numero) || ',';
    Numero := Numero + 1;
  end loop;
  pv_resp := Resultado;
end
```